# sqrt() method in c (Netbeans compiler vs. gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans

I am making some tutorial exercises for school practice in c. I have this little method(Heron's formula):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
.
.
double s = (a+b+c)/2.0;
double A = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) //a,b,c = 3,3,2
.
.
```

I can compile it with a gcc:

```
gcc exercise.c -o exercise -lm
```

Everything works well. Problem is, when i try to rewrite the same code in Netbeans, it throws this error:

```
/home/l2ysho/NetBeansProjects/cviko1/main.c:48: undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-       Linux/cviko1' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cviko1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/l2ysho/NetBeansProjects/cviko1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/l2ysho/NetBeansProjects/cviko1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 861ms)
```

In Netbeans, sqrt() method only works with a number (sqrt(2.5)), but not with a constant (sqrt(s)). I think, it is some problem with a Netbeans compiler. Do anyone have some similar issue?

Comment: netbeans doesn't pass `-lm` by default. You have to change process settings to add this option.

Comment: which version of gcc are you using? In recent versions, `-lm` flag isn't even needed (I found that to my surprise some weeks ago). Maybe the answer would be to upgrade your compiler, that would solve a lot of things :) oh BTW maybe you could post the contents of `nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk`, that would help too.

Comment: `sqrt(2.5)` is optimized by the compiler and probably replaced by a constant, the math function is never called. That's why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution. If you have the same problem, you can hard link a math.h in NetBeans IDE:

```
File->Project Properties->Build->Linker->Libraries->add Library/add standard Library
```

I also tried add an -lm argument to NetBeans compilator configuration, but this isn't worked.

Comment: Tried with `File->Project Properties->Build->Linker->Compilation Line->Additional Options` and setting **-lm** argument here and works now. Thanks!

Comment: confirmed: adding -lm to the additional options of the compiler does not work. you need to add the standard library "mathmatics" to the linker config